# Are OAuth users required to have their own location?

Tags: square

In SquareUp we have multiple apps and each app has one specific location.

Currently in the "development" app, we have all of the locations for all of our OAuth users listed.

Do we need to get each OAuth user to create a location for their self?

Answer (score 0):

No. When a merchant creates a Square account, a single location will be generated for them. They have the ability to create more or rename their location themselves, though.